# getopts is not sending my options to standard out

Tags: linux, bash, getopts

I'm beginning to experiment with getopts but am running into a few errors. When I enter an invalid option such as -A the program output is not what it needs to be.

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 -h [database host] -d [test database name]"
    exit 1
}

while getopts “:h:d:” opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    h)
      db_host=$OPTARG
      ;;
    d)
      test_db=$OPTARG
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" 1>&2
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo “Option -$OPTARG requires an argument.” 1>$2
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z $db_host ] || [ -z $test_db ]; then
    usage
else
    echo "Your host is $db_host and your test database is $test_db."
fi
```

Example program output:

```
./opt.sh: illegal option -- A
Invalid option: -
Usage: ./opt.sh -h [database host] -d [test database name]
```

So, basically two questions:

1) I want to get rid of this first error message altogether. I want to provide my own error messages.
2) Why isn't my script producing "Invalid option: -A" instead of just "Invalid option: -"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong types of quotes around the options argument to `getopts`, they're "curly quotes" instead of ASCII double quotes. As a result, `:` wasn't the first character of the options, so you weren't getting silent error reporting.

Change it to

```
while getopts ':h:d:' opt; do
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the quotations. I only have one "double quote" key on my keyboard and that is the same key as the "single quote"

These changes don't work. Just spits out "Invalid option: -?"

Comment: Look at the code in the question, you have curly quotes around the argument to `getopts`. It looks like you used a word processor and it did "smart quote" replacement.

Comment: Actually when I was looking at my script I noticed the issues with the quotes. Not sure how that happend -- good eye. The quoting fixed the issue, as the "silent reporting" wasn't being looked at due to the wrong quoting. I didn't need to change $OPTARG to $opt in the case statement, however.